# Can I use a fraction of vector to reverse cross product?

Tags: vectors, cross-product

The cross product is defined by the formula

$$ \vec A_i \times  \vec B_j = \|A\|\,\|B\| \sin\alpha = \vec C_k \tag{1}$$

Where $\alpha$ is angle between vectors $A$ and $B$. $C$ is a pseudovector perpendicular to $A$ and $B$. And i, j, k is standard basis direction mutually perpendicular to each other.

Assuming $\alpha$ it equals $90$ degrees then $\sin90=1$.
**This discussion is only for this case.**

Reverse cross product we encounter for a problem

$$ \vec C_k \times \vec A_i = \vec B`_j \tag{2}$$

The $B`$ vector has the correct direction but its value usually not equal $B$, because use $(1)$

$$ \left(\|A\| \, \|B\|\right)_k \times  \vec A_i =\|A\|^2 \, \|B\| = \vec B`_j \tag{3}$$

but using the proportion $(1)$ we can easily reverse them

$$AB=C \rightarrow B={C\over A} \tag{4}$$

If we find the inverse of the vector $A$, we can in this case when $\alpha=90$ degrees reverse cross product. How to get a vector $1/A$? The value of the vector is
$$\|A\|= \sqrt{a_x^2 + a_y ^2 + a_z^2} = A $$
we must fulfill the condition 
$$\|A\|\;\left\|{1\over A}\right\| =1 \\[20 pt]
\sqrt{a_x^2 + a_y ^2 + a_z^2}\frac{1}{\sqrt{ a_x^2 + a_y ^2 + a_z^2}} = 1 $$

this condition fulfill vector

$$\overrightarrow {1\over A} =\left( \frac{a_x}{\|A\|^2} ,\;\frac{a_y}{\|A\|^2},\; \frac{a_z}{\|A\|^2}\right)      \tag{5}    $$

This vector has the same direction as the vector A but inverse value.

Reverse cross product $(2)$ we have now
$$ \vec C_k \times \overrightarrow {\frac {1} {A_i}} =\|A\|\;\|B\|\;\left\|{1\over A}\right\| = \|B\| = B`_j \tag{6}$$

Whether saving a fraction of a vector $1/A$ is correct?

Comment: The symbol $\times$ is available as \times [wrapped by dollar symbols].

Comment: Something is wrong with your definition of cross product. It's a vector, not a number

Comment: What do all of those subscripts mean?

Comment: @Rumpelstiltskin What is wrong?

Comment: @amd i, j, k are unit version on the main axes. They are perpendicular to each other.

Comment: So, does that mean that $\vec A_i$ really means, in more conventional notation, the vector $A\vec i$, where $A$ is some scalar?

Comment: @amd \vec A_i is means vector \vec A on the "i" direction.

Comment: You should make that clear in your question. That’s a rather non-standard notation.